# Helmholtz decomposition implementation

Tags: reference-request, decomposition, derivative

I need to perform the [Helmholtz decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition) of a 2D flow. An old and obvious problem is the numerical differentiation (largely amplifying the noise).

I do understand the procedure I am just looking for useful tips and tricks or a literature reference -- surely I am not the first one to perform the task.

I am aware that there was a matlab package where the decomposition was implemented. But it worked only for square input matrices.

**Do you know any algorithm other than straightforward discretization of integrals and derivatives?**

Comment: Have you looked on https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/26701/how-to-compute-the-helmholtz-decomposition-of-2d-and-3d-vector-fields and https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/16360/quick-and-simple-discrete-2d-helmholtz-hodge-decomposition-using-ffts?